# Why the following PHP code creates an infinite loop?

Tags: php, infinite-loop

```
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3);
reset($arr);
while (list($k, $v) = each($arr)) {
    print "$k => $v\n";
    $h[] = $arr;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `foreach($arr as $k => $v)` instead of `reset($arr); while(...)`

The reason why it's failing is that `$h[] = $arr;` resets the internal array pointer if it's at the end and thus the loop starts from the beginning.

Comment: He is looping over the array ``$arr``, ``$h`` is a different array ... Or did I miss something obvious?

Comment: He's using `$arr` as an rvalue. And copying the array apparently resets its pointer. Just another example why PHP is awesome!</irony>

Comment: `while (list($k, $v) = each($arr))` is the PHP3 way to iterate over an array. So that's working fine - but it stops doing so as soon as you modify the array (including its internal pointer). `foreach()` doesn't suffer from this problem as it always operates on a copy of the array.

Comment: Ok, that seems to be it. I would say this isn't a quirk but an obvious bug ... :-/

Answer (score 0):

ThiefMaster is right. With the assignment of `$arr` you reset the internal pointer when you're at the last element. When using `foreach()` you will work with a copy of the original array.